# how to sort files on server in the client-server model?

Tags: java

I am developing a client server model in which i need to send some TCP dump data to the server. The server will sort the data and will send it back to the client. I wanted to know how to go about this procedure.

Comment: Your question needs to be much more specific.

Comment: sir, i edited the question. Plz have a look again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put files to list, then use `Collections.sort(list, comparator)`. Implement your own Comparator if you need some application specific sorting criteria.